# Do we need the gsutil tool installed in system to access google Cloud

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Am developing an application in java and i had installed the [gsutil Tool](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) in my local system to access the Google cloud storage for read and write operations. I had referred the app engine document [Google Cloud Storage Java API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview#Prerequisites) .It says to install the gsutil tool for accessing buckets for read and write operations. Now my doubt is, Later on at the time of deploying my application in any web servers, Do i need to install and configure the [gsutil Tool](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) in web server?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GSUtil only provides command line interface for Google Cloud Storage on top of Clouds Storage API, instead of using it you can access the API directly.

Comment: To Give permissions to the bucket or objects i followed the instructions using the Service Account Name in team. but it failed so as per alternative way i installed the gsutil tool in the system. Now my doubt is do i need to install the same gsutil tool in any of the web server when i launch the application

Comment: @sathya As I said Its only a command line tool and nothing else, it done't have any effect just being installed on the server.

Comment: so you mean i should create an oAuth 2.0 client id for API access that shown in the Google API console of my account right?